# Anti XSS Library removing UL tag. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, antixsslibrary

I am using the [Microsoft anti xss library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) and I noticed that for some reason it is removing the `<ul>` tag.  I can't figure out why. For instance:

```
 string html = @"<ul><li>this is a test </li></ul>";
 string sanitized = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(html);
```

This is returning:

```
   \r\n<li>this is a test </li>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related to a bug in Sanitizer: [link](http://wpl.codeplex.com/workitem/17246)

Comment: Hmm. I guess try a older version till this is fixed and see what happens? Anyone know where to get an older version. Nuget seems to only have the newest version.

Comment: You can download the [source](http://wpl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/72192) from one of the earlier check-ins and compile it. It contains v3.0, v3.1, and v4.0

Comment: Ya seems like going back to 4.0.1 does the trick. So must be a problem with latest versio.

Comment: @Tung, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://wpl.codeplex.com/workitem/17246).  Users who would like to use one of the older versions can acquire them [here](http://wpl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72192)

@Ray Cheng, cheers